# How can I toggle line numbers on all windows in the current tab in vim, except NerdTree?

Tags: vim

In my `.vimrc`, I want a key combination that will toggle line numbers on all windows in the current tab I'm looking at except for the:

- NERDTree window
- Tagbar window

The Tagbar I'm using is this: https://github.com/preservim/tagbar

If I simply use: `:set number` and `:set nonumber`, that only effects the active window, so if my active window happens to be NERDTree, my shortcut will enable line numbers on NERDTree, which is not what I want.

Also, if I have multiple windows open, I want it to enable/disable numbers on all my windows - not just the active one, but ignore the NERDTree window, and the Tagbar window.

Is this possible?

Comment: Consider using the [vi.se] Stack Exchange for questions on Vim.

Comment: @filbranden I forgot there was a dedicated site for vim/vi - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found it:

```
windo if &filetype != 'nerdtree' && &filetype != 'tagbar' | set number | set relativenumber | endif
```

the `| set relativenumber` is only if you want that as well, but demonstrates how to set multiple options.